# Click event not being called on internal div

Tags: jquery, css, click

I need to write jQuery code that when I click anywhere on the div I call it an event of jQuery, and when they click on a specific item, that within this div, do not call the click event. The class "testes" should not call the click.

However, the structure that I have to use is as below, because it is a specific jQuery.

Below is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="tiles red">
    <div class="live-tile" id="tile1" data-mode="flip">        
        <div>
            <div class="testes"><a class="full" href="#"><p>* CNAE<br /></a></div>* CBO<br />* CID-10<br /></p>
            <span class="tile-title"><p>Clique para voltar</p></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Cadastros básicos</p>
            <span class="tile-title">back title</span>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function () {
  $(".live-tile").click(function () {
    $(this).liveTile('play');                
  });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this using [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
$(function () {
  $(".live-tile").click(function () {
    $(this).liveTile('play');                
  });

  $(".testes").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();                
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `.bind()` the event to your element and prevent bubbling:

```
$(".live-tile").bind("click", function(){
    $(this).liveTile('play');                
}, false)
```

This form of `bind()` is a jQuery function of the form:

```
.bind( eventType [, eventData ], preventBubble )
```

Answer (score 0):

A few others answered your question while I threw together the [code in JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EqQZV/). But, here is specifically how to do it for your code.

```
$(function () {
$(".live-tile").click(function () {
    alert(".live-tile");              
});

$(".testes").click(function(e) {
    alert(".testes");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
});
```

[More info on event bubbling and stopping propogation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli)