# How to close a div by clicking anywhere outside the div and not inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events, event-bubbling

I have implemented the following piece that works almost everywhere on the page.

```
$(document).click(function(event){
    if($("#div_to_close").is(":visible")){
       $("#div_to_close").hide();   
    }
});

$("#div_to_close").click(function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

This is working fine anywhere on the page but there are certain elements on the page where click handlers are implemented and event.stopPropagation() is used in the hadler. In all such elements the div does not close.

This happens because the click event for these elements do not bubble upto the document and hence the handler for doc is not called.

How do I come across this?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mickeymoon/X6nm9/)

Comment: An other way, making DIV focusable: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17966127/1414562

Comment: Have you tried not calling event.stopPropagation() in these handlers?

Comment: Don't use `event.stopPropagation();` it will completely ignores the possibility that any other code on the page might need to know about that event. [detailed article](http://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/)

Comment: @A.Wolff I was trying like this but could not succeed. http://jsfiddle.net/2bfJC/1/ any problem there?

Comment: @C-link It should be like this, taking into accound child element clicked: http://jsfiddle.net/2bfJC/2/

Comment: @C-link `taking into accound child element clicked` otherwise clicking on any child element would still close the DIV (not expected result) http://jsfiddle.net/2bfJC/3/