# jQuery .hide() not working for $(document).click

Tags: jquery, html

i am trying to create a drop down menu using jQuery.

HTML is:

```
<div id="cats">
    <div id="cat_ram">
        <span>RAM</span>
        <div class="cat_arrow"></div>
        <div class="cat_options">
            <ul class="cat_list">
                <li>1GB</li>
                <li>2GB</li>
                <li>3GB</li>
                <li>4GB</li>
           </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('.cat_options').hide();

    $('.cat_arrow').click(function(){
            $('.cat_options').toggle();
        });


        $(document).click(function(){
        if($('.cat_options').is(':visible')){
            $('.cat_options').hide();
            }
        })
});
```

**Here is what i am trying to accomplish:**

1)when **.cat_arrow** is clicked the drop down menu i.e **.cat_options** should be shown.And when it is clicked again it should hide.

2)While **.cat_options** is visible if a click event occurs any where else on the page (not on .cat_arrow) **.cat_options** should hide.

**Now the problem is that:**

1)For above code the **.cat_options** never shows.
And if i add another if condition like this

```
if($('.cat_options').is(':hidden')){
        $('.cat_options').show();
```

Then clicking anywhere in the document would make the **.cat_options** visible i.e the **.cat_arrow** would become useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop propagation on `.cat_arrow` click:

```
$('.cat_arrow').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.cat_options').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Can you explain a little how it worked?? Why did it worked by putting it with toggle(). I think i should have been with the second part i.e $(document).click......?Sorry but i haven't quite understood the concepts involved here:(

Comment: See: https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/ `Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.` Otherwise, your click event bound to `document` level would be fired and so hide the element. An other way would be to filter in `document` click handler the event target to see if it is descendant of `.cat_arrow` or `.cat_arrow` itself. And finally, a completly different way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17966127/1414562

Comment: OK! isn't it the document element it self the element due to which the clcik event was triggered?? so why would an element lower in DOM tree get notified?? i mean here the second part of code would get executed.

Comment: can you suggest some reading on the topics concerned with my problem.

Comment: You have to understand event propagation, bubbling and capturing (not relevant here) event phase: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing/4616720#4616720

Comment: OK! Thank you so much for helping me out i'll read both these questions.