# Hide Pop up onclick Outside

Tags: javascript

Once click on Text, we are displaying Pop up box....

**Requirement** :

When user click on **outside popup**, i am trying to **hide** the pop up here : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/VNxMYO ....

**Issue** :

For that I tried below code , but after that when i tried to **change** font-family through **dropdown**, then popup will close....

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e) 
    {
        var container = $('.white_content');

        if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
        {
            container.hide();           
            $('.font-select').css('display', 'none'); 
        }
    });
```

```js
$(document).mouseup(function(e) 
 {
     var container = $('.dark_content');

     // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
     if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
     {
         container.hide();
     }
 });
 
// close text pop up onclick outside

$(document).mouseup(function(e) 
 {
     var container = $('.white_content');

     // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
     if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
     {
         container.hide();
     }
 }); 

 // end


 //font color
 var className;

 function changeColor(data) {
  var color = $(data).css('background-color');
  var changeColor = $(className).css('color', color);
 }

 //font color end

 // Display pop up next to text
 function closePopUp(el) {
  el.style.display = 'none';
  $('.font-select').css('display', 'none');
  openID = null
 }

 function openPopUp(el) {
  // console.log(el);
  if (openID != null) {
   closePopUp(openID)
  }


  var styleTop = el.style.top;
  var styleLeft = el.style.left;

  styleTop = parseInt(styleTop.substring(3 , -1)) + 130;
  styleLeft = parseInt(styleLeft.substring(3 , -1)) + 30;

  $('.font-select:first').css({
   display: 'block',
   left: styleLeft + 'px',
   top: styleTop + 'px',
   zIndex: 1010
  });

  //font color

  var colorID = el.id.substring(5);
  className = '#' + colorID;

  //font color end

  el.style.display = 'block';
  openID = el;
 }

 function fontRange(e) {
  var element = e.parentElement.id;
  element = "#edit_" + element.split("_")[1];
  $(element).css('font-size', e.value + 'px');
 }

 let openID = null;

 var target;
 const imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

 let jsonData =  {
  "path" : " fb post\/",
  "info" : {
    "author" : "",
    "keywords" : "",
    "file" : "fb post",
    "date" : "sRGB",
    "title" : "",
    "description" : "Normal",
    "generator" : "Export Kit v1.2.8"
  },
  "name" : "fb post",
  "layers" : [
    {
      "x" : 0,
      "height" : 789,
      "layers" : [
        {
          "x" : 0,
          "color" : "0xFF606D",
          "height" : 789,
          "y" : 0,
          "width" : 940,
          "shapeType" : "rectangle",
          "type" : "shape",
          "name" : "bg_rectangle_1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 0,
          "height" : 788,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 788,
              "src" : "2627e475d59546ec8522df6f89713867_frame0.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 506,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "bg_image"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 0,
          "width" : 506,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_image_1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 465,
          "height" : 411,
          "src" : "5faf41823c9ccd92485912c6fa6befcc_frame1.png",
          "y" : 206,
          "width" : 443,
          "type" : "image",
          "name" : "shape_1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 228,
          "height" : 150,
          "src" : "724c7c5b06fae34d68633c349ccb752a_frame2.png",
          "y" : 609,
          "width" : 175,
          "type" : "image",
          "name" : "shape_2"
        },
        {
          "justification" : "center",
          "font" : "Coustard",
          "x" : 576,
          "y" : 294,
          "src" : "db4922cce0cd771c28fe5c818ae313e4_Font249.ttf",
          "width" : 221,
          "type" : "text",
          "color" : "0xFFFFFF",
          "size" : 67,
          "text" : "BE MY",
          "height" : 50,
          "name" : "edit_be"
        },
        {
          "justification" : "center",
          "font" : "Coustard",
          "x" : 570,
          "y" : 561,
          "src" : "db4922cce0cd771c28fe5c818ae313e4_Font249.ttf",
          "width" : 236,
          "type" : "text",
          "color" : "0xFFFFFF",
          "size" : 37,
          "text" : "READ MORE",
          "height" : 28,
          "name" : "edit_read"
        },
        {
          "justification" : "center",
          "font" : "Coustard-Black",
          "x" : 549,
          "y" : 353,
          "src" : "0a7fb3015bb19745da114bc581e96947_Font248.ttf",
          "width" : 276,
          "type" : "text",
          "color" : "0xFFFFFF",
          "size" : 67,
          "text" : "VALEN",
          "height" : 51,
          "name" : "edit_valen"
        },
        {
          "justification" : "center",
          "font" : "Coustard-Black",
          "x" : 533,
          "y" : 411,
          "src" : "0a7fb3015bb19745da114bc581e96947_Font248.ttf",
          "width" : 306,
          "type" : "text",
          "color" : "0xFFFFFF",
          "size" : 104,
          "text" : "TINE",
          "height" : 80,
          "name" : "edit_tine"
        },
        {
          "justification" : "center",
          "font" : "Coustard-Black",
          "x" : 274,
          "y" : 641,
          "src" : "0a7fb3015bb19745da114bc581e96947_Font248.ttf",
          "width" : 74,
          "type" : "text",
          "color" : "0xFFFFFF",
          "size" : 23,
          "text" : "SAVE",
          "height" : 17,
          "name" : "edit_save"
        },
        {
          "justification" : "center",
          "font" : "Coustard-Black",
          "x" : 274,
          "y" : 665,
          "src" : "0a7fb3015bb19745da114bc581e96947_Font248.ttf",
          "width" : 71,
          "type" : "text",
          "color" : "0xFFFFFF",
          "size" : 28,
          "text" : "THE",
          "height" : 21,
          "name" : "edit_the"
        },
        {
          "justification" : "center",
          "font" : "Coustard-Black",
          "x" : 274,
          "y" : 693,
          "src" : "0a7fb3015bb19745da114bc581e96947_Font248.ttf",
          "width" : 72,
          "type" : "text",
          "color" : "0xFFFFFF",
          "size" : 22,
          "text" : "DATE",
          "height" : 17,
          "name" : "edit_date"
        }
      ],
      "y" : 0,
      "width" : 940,
      "type" : "group",
      "name" : "fb_post_4"
    }
  ]
};

 const containerElement = $('#container');
 const fileUp = $('#fileup');

 $(function() {

  // below code will upload image onclick mask image

  containerElement.click(function(e) {
   // filtering out non-canvas clicks
   if (e.target.tagName !== 'CANVAS') return;

   // getting absolute points relative to container
   const absX = e.offsetX + e.target.parentNode.offsetLeft + e.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
   const absY = e.offsetY + e.target.parentNode.offsetTop + e.currentTarget.offsetTop;

   const $canvasList = $(this).find('canvas');
   // moving all canvas parents on the same z-index
   $canvasList.parent().css({
    zIndex: 0
   });

   $canvasList.filter(function() { // filtering only applicable canvases
    const bbox = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    const canvasTop = bbox.top + window.scrollY;
    const canvasLeft = bbox.left + window.scrollX;
    return (
      absX >= canvasLeft && absX <= canvasLeft + bbox.width &&
      absY >= canvasTop && absY <= canvasTop + bbox.height)
   }).each(function() { // checking white in a click position
    const x = absX - this.parentNode.offsetLeft - e.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
    const y = absY - this.parentNode.offsetTop - e.currentTarget.offsetTop;
    const pixel = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
    if (pixel[3] === 255) {
     $(this).parent().css({
      zIndex: 2
     })
     target = this.id;
     console.log(target);
     setTimeout(fileUp.click.bind(fileUp), 20);
    }
   })
  });

  // Below code will fetch mask images from json file

  function getAllSrc(layers) {
   let arr = [];
   layers.forEach(layer => {
    if (layer.src) {
     arr.push({
      src: layer.src,
      x: layer.x,
      y: layer.y,
      height: layer.height,
      width: layer.width,
      name: layer.name
     });
    } else if (layer.layers) {
     let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
     if (newArr.length > 0) {
      newArr.forEach(({
           src,
           x,
           y,
           height,
           width,
           name
          }) => {
       arr.push({
        src,
        x: (layer.x + x),
        y: (layer.y + y),
        height,
        width,
        name: (name)
       });
      });
     }
    }
   });
   return arr;
  }

  function json(data)

  {
   var width = 0;
   var height = 0;

   let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

   let layer1 = data.layers;
   width = layer1[0].width;
   height = layer1[0].height;
   let counter = 0;
   let table = [];

   containerElement.css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');

   for (let {
    src,
    x,
    y,
    name
   } of arr) {


    //Get Height and width of mask image [ edit button ]
    var ImagePosition = arr;
    //code end

    // Display icon only for mask images

    if (name.indexOf('mask_') !== -1) {
     var imageUrl1 = imageUrl;
    } else {
     var imageUrl1 = '';
          // click work only on mask image
           $('.masked-img').css('pointer-events', 'none');
          // click end
    }
    //code end

    var mask = $(".container").mask({
     imageUrl: imageUrl1,
     maskImageUrl: 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + src,
     onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
      // Mask image positions
      img.css({
       "position": "absolute",
       "left": x + "px",
       "top": y + "px"
      });
      // end

     },
     id: counter
    });
    table.push(mask);
    fileup.onchange = function() {

     let mask2 = table[target];
     const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
     document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";

     //  Edit image

     if ($(".masked-img" + newImageLoadedId).length === 1) {
      $("<span class=\"pip pip" + newImageLoadedId + "\">" +
        "<a onclick='document.getElementById(\"dark" + newImageLoadedId + "\").style.display=\"block\";'><span class=\"edit edit" + newImageLoadedId + "\" >Edit </span></a>" +
        "</span>").insertAfter(".masked-img" + newImageLoadedId).css({
       "left": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].x + (ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].width / 2) + "px",
       "top": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].y + (ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].height / 2) + "px"
      });;
      $("<div id=\'dark" + newImageLoadedId + "\' class=\'dark_content\'>" +
        $('#demoTemplate').html() +
        "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"document.getElementById(\'dark" + newImageLoadedId + "\').style.display=\'none\'\">Close</a>" + "</div>").appendTo(".pip" + newImageLoadedId).css({
       "left": $('.edit' + newImageLoadedId).width() + 2 + "px",
       "top": "0px"
      });

     }
     // Edit code end here....
     //  Remove image

     $("<br/><span id=\"" + newImageLoadedId + "\" class=\"remove\">Remove</span>").insertAfter(".masked-img" + newImageLoadedId).css({
      "left": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].x + (ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].width / 2) + "px",
      "top": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].y + (ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].height / 2 + 25) + "px"
     });

     $(".remove").click(function(event) {
      const canvasId = "canvas#" + event.currentTarget.id;
      // Delete the image
      const ctx = $("canvas")[event.currentTarget.id].getContext("2d");
      ctx.fillStyle = "white"
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500)
      // Delete the Remove button
      $(this).next().find('.edit').remove()
      $(this).remove();

     });

     // Remove image code end here....
    };
    counter++;
   }
   drawText(data);
  }
  json(jsonData);
 }); // end of document ready

 //Fetch text

 const fonts = []; // caching duplicate fonts

 function drawText(layer) {

  if (layer.type === 'image') return;

  if (!layer.type || layer.type === 'group') {
   return layer.layers.forEach(drawText)
  }

  if (layer.type === 'text') {
   const url = 'https://i.imgur.com/' + layer.src;

   if (!fonts.includes(url)) {
    fonts.push(url);
    $("style").prepend("@font-face {\n" +
      "\tfont-family: \"" + layer.font + "\";\n" +
      "\tsrc: url(" + url + ") format('truetype');\n" +
      "}");
   }

   // Below is POP UP Code
   const lightId = 'light' + layer.name
   const lightIdString = '#' + lightId
   $('.container').append(
     '<input id="font" style="display:none"><a id ="' + layer.name + '" onclick="openPopUp(' + lightId + ')"' +
     '<div class="txtContainer" id = "text" contenteditable="true" ' +
     'style="' +
     'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
     'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' +
     'font-size: ' + layer.size + 'px; ' +
     '">' + layer.text + '</div></a>' +
     '<div id="light' + layer.name + '" class="white_content" style="' +
     'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
     'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' + '"> ' +
     $('#template2').html() +
     '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closePopUp(' + lightId + ')">Close</a></div> <div>'
   );
   document.getElementById(lightId).style.left = layer.x + document.getElementById(layer.name).offsetWidth + 'px'
   // Above is POP UP Code
  }

 }
 // text end

 // images drag

 (function($) {
  var JQmasks = [];
  $.fn.mask = function(options) {
   // This is the easiest way to have default options.
   var settings = $.extend({
    // These are the defaults.
    maskImageUrl: undefined,
    imageUrl: undefined,
    scale: 1,
    id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
    x: 0, // image start position
    y: 0, // image start position
    onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
   }, options);


   var container = $(this);

   let prevX = 0,
     prevY = 0,
     draggable = false,
     img,
     canvas,
     context,
     image,
     timeout,
     initImage = false,
     startX = settings.x,
     startY = settings.y,
     div;

   container.mousePosition = function(event) {
    return {
     x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
     y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
    };
   }

   container.selected = function(ev) {
    var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
    var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
     var offset = $(this).offset()
     var x = pos.x - offset.left;
     var y = pos.y - offset.top;
     var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
     return d[0] > 0
    });

    JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
     var id  
     = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
     if (el.id == id)
      el.item.enable();
     else el.item.disable();
    });
   };

   container.enable = function() {
    draggable = true;
    $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
    div.css({
     "z-index": 2
    });
   }

   container.disable = function() {
    draggable = false;
    $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
    div.css({
     "z-index": 1
    });
   }


   container.onDragStart = function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.getContext) {
     var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;

     $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
     container.selected(evt);
     prevX = evt.clientX;
     prevY = evt.clientY;
     var img = new Image();
     evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 10, 10);
     evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'anything');

    }
   };

   container.getImagePosition = function() {
    return {
     x: settings.x,
     y: settings.y,
     scale: settings.scale
    };
   };

   container.onDragOver = function(evt) {

    if (evt.target.getContext) {
     var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
     if (pixel[3] === 255) {
      if (draggable && $(canvas).attr("active") === "true") {
       var x = settings.x + evt.clientX - prevX;
       var y = settings.y + evt.clientY - prevY;
       if (x == settings.x && y == settings.y)
        return; // position has not changed
       settings.x += evt.clientX - prevX;
       settings.y += evt.clientY - prevY;
       prevX = evt.clientX;
       prevY = evt.clientY;
       clearTimeout(timeout);
       timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        container.updateStyle();
        renderInnerImage();
       }, 20);
      }
     } else {
      evt.stopPropagation();
      return false;
     }
    }
   };

   container.updateStyle = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     context.beginPath();
     context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
     image = new Image();
     image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
     image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
     image.onload = function() {
      canvas.width = image.width;
      canvas.height = image.height;
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
      div.css({
       "width": image.width,
       "height": image.height
      });
      resolve();
     };
    });
   };

   function renderInnerImage() {
    img = new Image();
    img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
    img.src = settings.imageUrl;
    img.onload = function() {
     settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
     settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
     context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
     context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
     initImage = false;
    };
   }

   // change the draggable image

   container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
    console.log("load");
    //if (img)
    // img.remove();
    // reset the code.
    settings.y = startY;
    settings.x = startX;
    prevX = prevY = 0;
    settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    initImage = true;
    container.updateStyle().then(renderInnerImage);
    // sirpepole  Add this
    return settings.id;
   };


   // change the masked Image
   container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
    canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
    settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
    div = $("<div/>", {
     "class": "masked-img"
    }).append(canvas);

    // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event)
    div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {
     if (event.handled === false) return;
     event.handled = true;
     container.onDragStart(event);
    });

    div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
     if (event.handled === false) return;
     event.handled = true;
     container.selected(event);
    });

    div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
    container.append(div);
    if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
     settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
    container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
   };
   container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
   JQmasks.push({
    item: container,
    id: settings.id
   })
   // Edit image
   div.addClass('masked-img' + settings.id);
   // code end
   return container;
  };
 }(jQuery));

 //Zoom in , Zoom out , Rotate code

 document.getElementById("img").src = json(data);

 var angle = 0;
 var scale = 1;
 var $img = $('#image');

 $img.on('transform', function() {
  $img.css('transform', `rotate(${angle}deg) scale(${scale})`);
 });

 $('.js-rotate-right').on('click', function() {
  angle += 15;
  $img.trigger('transform');
 });

 $('.js-rotate-left').on('click', function() {
  angle -= 15;
  $img.trigger('transform');
 });

 $('.js-zoom-in').on('click', function() {
  scale += 0.25;
  if (scale == 2.25) {
   scale = 2;
  };
  $img.trigger('transform');
 });

 $('.js-zoom-out').on('click', function() {
  scale -= 0.25;
  if (scale == 0) {
   scale = 0.25;
  }
  $img.trigger('transform');
 });
```

```css
.container {
   background: silver;
   position: relative;
  }

  .container img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 250px;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   margin: auto;
   z-index: 999;
  }

  .masked-img {
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
  }

  .txtContainer {
   position: absolute;
   text-align: center;
   color: #FFF
  }

  .txtContainer:hover {
   background: red;
   padding: 1px;
   border-style: dotted;
  }

  .pip {
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0;
   position: absolute;
  }

  .remove {
   background: #444;
   border: 1px solid black;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   cursor: pointer;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 3;
  }

  .remove:hover {
   background: white;
   color: black;
  }

  .edit {
   display: block;
   background: #444;
   border: 1px solid black;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   cursor: pointer;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 3;
  }

  .edit:hover {
   background: white;
   color: black;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 3;
  }

  .white_content {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   top: 25%;
   left: 25%;
   width: 50%;
   height: 50%;
   padding: 16px;
   border: 16px solid orange;
   background-color: white;
   z-index: 1002;
   overflow: auto;
  }

  .dark_content {
   display: none;
   position: relative;
   top: 25%;
   left: 25%;
   width: 350px;
   height: 350px;
   padding: 16px;
   border: 16px solid orange;
   background-color: white;
   z-index: 1002;
   overflow: auto;
  }

  .radiobutton {
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   margin: 10px;
   cursor: pointer;
  }

  .radiobutton span {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   padding: 0;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   border-radius: 100%;
   background: #eeeeee;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
   transition: ease .3s;
  }

  .radiobutton span:hover {
   padding: 10px;
  }

  .orange .radiobutton span {
   background: #FF5722;
  }

  .red .radiobutton span {
   background: #FFC107;
  }

  .radiocolor {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background: transparent;
   /*transition: ease .3s;*/
   z-index: -1;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-Google-Web-Font-Selector-With-jQuery-Fontselect/fontselect.css" />
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-Google-Web-Font-Selector-With-jQuery-Fontselect/jquery.fontselect.js"></script>

<style>
  .font-select {
   display: none;
  }
</style>

<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >


<div id="container"class="container">
</div>

<template id='demoTemplate'>
   <span>
      <div class="btn-group">
         <button type="button" class="js-zoom-in">Zoom In</button>
         <button type="button" class="js-zoom-out">Zoom Out</button>
         <button type="button" class="js-rotate-right">Rotate Right</button>
         <button type="button" class="js-rotate-left">Rotate Left</button>
      </div>
      <img id="image" src ="" style ="display:none">             
   </span>
</template>

<template id='template2'>
   <input type="range" min="60" max="90" oninput="fontRange(this)" onchange="fontRange(this)">
   <label class="orange">
      <input type="radio" name="color" value="orange" style="display:none" >
      <div class="radiocolor"></div>
      <div class="radiobutton"><span onclick="changeColor(this)"></span></div>
   </label>
   <label class="red">
      <input type="radio" name="color" value="red" style="display:none" >
      <div class="radiocolor"></div>
      <div class="radiobutton"><span onclick="changeColor(this)"></span></div>
   </label>
   <script>

$(function() {
   $('#font').fontselect().change(function() {

    // replace + signs with spaces for css
    var font = $(this).val().replace(/\+/g, ' ');

    // split font into family and weight
    font = font.split(':');

    // set family on paragraphs
    $('p').css('font-family', font[0]);
   });

   $('.font-select').click(function (index) {
    var targetFontFamily = index.target.style.fontFamily;
    var targetFontWeight = index.target.style.fontWeight;
    $(className).css({
     fontFamily: targetFontFamily,
     fontWeight: targetFontWeight
    });
   })
  });
    
</script>
   
   
</template>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close a div by clicking outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965839/close-a-div-by-clicking-outside)

Comment: @SyedMohamedAladeen thanks for comment , i already checked that link, but they are using different logic & that will not fit for my code as both code are completely different.....

Comment: your snippet runs differently as compared to your question . please clear that and what exactly you want  .\

Comment: @Haroonnasir thanks for comment , i want to hide pop up when we click outside.....

Comment: Your `closePopup` function can receive the `click` event as an argument. Inside the function, you can add an `if` block so that if  the event's target (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) is your dropdown element, your code will not close the popup.

Comment: You have a lot of code in your question that is unrelated to the issue so it's a bit difficult to isolate the problem. I'll write a code sample that does what it sounds like you're trying to accomplish, though. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @Cat please ignore the other code..... i posted the exact code in top of the question, you can look only into that.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to do, simply add your dropdown class to your `container var` and your problem solved

```
var container = $('.white_content, .font-select');
```

now when you select your dropdown, pop-up not closing

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
In response to comments, one further suggestion, specific to the code posted in the question, is to try:

```
document.addEventListener("input", closePopup);
function closePopup(event){
  if(event.target == document.getElementById("font")){
    console.log("font changed");
    popup.style.display = "none"; // `popup` must have a reference to the popup 
  }
}
```

When the hidden `input` element with the id `font` receives input (presumably from the user making a selection in one of the "dropdowns"), the popup should close -- although I have not been able to test this.

---

**Edit 2:**
And another, if the problem is that `dropdown` only exists in a template element and you need a local copy that you can use in the document, is to make a copy with [Node.cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode):

```js
// Copy the template's content
const templateElement = document.getElementById("templateForDropdown"),
      originalDropdown = templateElement.content, // It's in the .content property
      copyOfDropdown = originalDropdown.cloneNode(true); // `true` clones descendants
copyOfDropdown.id = "dropdown1"; // Don't use the same `id` twice

// Add the copy to the DOM
const container = document.getElementById("container");
container.appendChild(copyOfDropdown);

console.log("(You have to click 'full-page' to properly view the SO snippet results)");
console.log(container.outerHTML);
```

```css
#container{ width: 120px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid grey; padding:  10px 20px 60px 20px; }
```

```html
<template id="templateForDropdown">
  <select id="dropdown0">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</template>

<div id="container">
  <h4>Dropdown...</h4>
</div>
```

(...or if the template is in another document or in an iframe, you'd need `Document.importNode()`.)

---

**Original answer:**
This should give you an idea of how to show a popup that can be hidden again by clicking outside of it. (The `else ... if` part ensures that clicking the dropdown or its children does not close the popup.) Feel free to modify it to suit your purpose.

```js
// Select particular elements
const button = document.getElementById("button");
const popup = document.getElementById("popup");
const dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");

// Listen for clicks
document.addEventListener("click", togglePopup);

// Respond to clicks
function togglePopup(event){
  // Show popup when user clicks button
  if(event.target == button){
    popup.style.display = "block";
  }
  // Otherwise...
  else {
    // ... As long as the click is not on dropdown or its children...
    if(event.target != dropdown && event.target.parentNode != dropdown){
      // ... close the popup
      popup.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#popup{ display: none; }
#container{ border: 1px solid grey; padding: 10px 20px 80px 20px; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="popup">I'm a popup</div>
<br />
<button id="button">Show Popup</button>
<br /><br />
<select id="dropdown">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, the issue is font family Dropdown is not displaying inside pop up box logically, so when i click on dropdown , it not closing pop up......

Comment: What does "is not displaying inside pop up box logically" mean? Is there no way to select the dropdown element to run conditional JS code (such as with `document.getElementById()`)?

Comment: in that ,  this line `<input id="font" style="display:none">` should display inside <template> tag, than dropdown will display logically inside pop, now i am using css to display dropdown inside pop up, so logically dropdown is not inside pop up......

Comment: I added one more suggestion in the answer now that I see you have a hidden input field (listening for the `input` event on that element, or if this doesn't work, you might try a different event such as `change`.) I hope this will help.

Comment: ...and I started to suspect the your real question might be about dealing with the  `template` element. So please see my additional edit about that if it might be what you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192105/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-cat).

Comment: hi @cat, yes true...... its problem with template, thanks a lot you took so much of your valuable time to help me.... but sorry as other answer helped me to solve the issue, i accepted that, i will check you edit and try to change the code structure according to that......