# Filter a Hyperlink in an Unordered List

Tags: jquery

I have the following code snapshot

```
<ul id="Boss">

      <li class="A">A-list 
        <ul>
          <li class="B">Blah Blah
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Medswer</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="B">Blah Blah BLah
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Brotx</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">The holy</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Terodvc</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
```

I am toggling the nodes to expand/collapse like this

```
$('#Boss').find('.A, .B, .C').filter(":not(:has(>a))").click(function () {
// code to toggle
return false;
}
```

However I want to avoid the nodes to toggle whenever an anchor is clicked.  So I added a filter but its not working

```
$('#Boss').find('.A, .B, .C').filter(":not(:has(>a))").click(..)
```

What am I doing wrong? Please suggest what code to put as filter as the other stuff is working pretty well and I do not want to change much

Thanks.

Comment: can u create jsfiddle for your code?

Comment: You should post valid `html` for `ul`, properly nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you want something like this ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/5fPhh/4/))

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="Boss">
    <li class="B">Blah Blah
        <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Medswer</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="B">Blah Blah BLah
        <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Brotx</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">The holy</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Terodvc</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    $('#Boss li').on('click', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).find('ul').slideToggle()
    });
});
```

Comment: `.not("a")` is irrelevant since you are using `e.stopPropagation()`. But i think you understood the question better :)

Comment: +1 but actually i am still confused on is this what OP really wants... Your `$(this).find('ul')` should take care of what we assume he is doing inside his handler(which OP has not posted)

Comment: @PSL, Impressive attitude mate, I'm also confused about it but made a guess but if `OP` wants what you gave him then you'll get my support(+1) and i'll delete mine :-)

Comment: actually I was just trying the code. So sorry for delay in responding. I will respond in a short while

Comment: Ok I did this http://jsfiddle.net/5fPhh/5/ and everything works perfect. Just one more issue. The anchors can contain "#" or a proper url. If it contains "#" don't do anything. If it contains a url, navigate to url keeping tree intact. I was able to achieve the url part, how do I handle the anchor part as clicking on the anchor opens a new page

Comment: It opens a new page now, what do you want ?

Comment: Try it in your site, it shouldn't open in a new window.

Comment: I want to open in a new window. I just don't want to do anything for anchors. See the updated fiddle jsfiddle.net/5fPhh/5

Comment: Add `target=_blank` in your a `tags` like `<a href='' target='_blank'>Link</a>`, it'll open a new tab, is that you want ?

Answer (score 1):

Events bubble up. So stop propagation at the anchor click event. Even if you mention filter still the click events on your anchors bubble up to the click event registered on the `li` that are on it parent/grandparent hierarchy. So one way you can do it to stop the propagation.

```
$('#Boss ul li > a').on('click', function(e){
     e.stopPropagation(); 
     e.preventDefault(); //prevent the default action of anchor required here since it wont go to its parent li which has a return false.
     // or combine them to return false; 
});
```

or you can filter it in the click event of `li` with a check

```
     if(!$(this).is(e.target)){ 
        //click did not happen on li, possibly on its descendants, do whatever you want.
      }
```

Comment: So you mean to say I will have to 'additionally' add code to the one I already have. I was thinking of a way to make it terse with that filter command but if there's no other way, I will go ahead with your approach

Comment: @user1089173 one more approach, not tested try it out. I will update

Comment: Can you expand that new update. Where do I add it? Also if the hyperlinks are not anchors but url's, they should open in a new window  so that users can continue working with the tree

Comment: @user1089173 oh so the anchors are not for showing menus? i think you should put up a demo... in your question.

Comment: Here's the demo - http://jsfiddle.net/5fPhh/5/ . I want href's with url's should open in a new tab/window. Href's with plains anchors (#) should be ignored

Comment: @user1089173 I think you should accept the other answer since it  seems like u are using that solution. You can give me an upvote though if I was of any help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should stop event propagation.

```
$("#clickable a").click(function(e) {
   //do something
   e.stopPropagation();
})
```

[See here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli).