# Nested element with events

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-events

I have an element that looks like this,

```
<div class='outer'>
    <div class='inner'></div>
</div>
```

I have 2 events on this DOM elements,

```
$('.outer').click(function(e){
    console.log("outer has been triggered");
});

$('.inner').click(function(e){
    console.log("inner has been triggered");
});
```

Now, if click `.outer` I get the "outer has been triggered" in my console, if I click `.inner` I get "outer has been triggered" and "inner has been triggered", is there a way to only trigger inners event on inners click and keep it nested within the outer div?

Here is an example, http://jsbin.com/bewukakakuju/2/edit

Comment: e.stopPropagation(); http://jsbin.com/meyulefoyave/1/edit. More info here: http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1369035/218196

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.inner').click(function(e){
    console.log("inner has been triggered");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Code without an **explanation** is rarely helpful.