# Prevent clicking element with ng-click from triggering anchor tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `<span>` with a ng-click handler inside of an `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="/foo/bar">
  <h1>Some title</h1>
  <span ng-click="doSomething()">Say Hi!</span>
</a>
```

When this span is clicked, how can I prevent the `<a>` tag from navigating to its location?

**Edit:** I found the answer - use `e.preventDefault();` not `e.stopPropagation();`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli

Comment: Not a duplicate. That question is asking about a *child* anchor tag triggering a parent's on-click handler.  My question is the reverse - how do you stop a child from triggering a *parent* anchor.  The solution is different:  In their question you use `event.stopPropagation()`, in mine you use `event.preventDefault();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use `$event.preventDefault()`. This is particular to stopping the default behavior of an HTML element, vs using `stopPropagation()` to stop an event from bubbling up the DOM tree and triggering other handlers.

In this case we are stopping the default behavior of a particular element, so `preventDefault()` is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `event.stopPropagation()` which prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree

```
<span ng-click="doSomething($event)">Say Hi!</span>
```

controller

```
$scope.doSomething = function (event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    // other code
}
```

Comment: This sort of functionality should be built in a directive not controller.

Comment: This doesn't seem to prevent navigation to the `a` element's href

Comment: did you add $event argument in html?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="/foo/bar">
  <h1>Some title</h1>
  <span prevent-click="doSomething()">Say Hi!</span>
</a>
```

Directive.js

```
.directive('preventClick', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                scope.$apply(attrs.preventClick);
            }
        }
    }
```