# Stop children of a DIV from firing events

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have the following DOM structure :

```
<div onclick="function">
<element1 />
<element2 />
<element3 />
....
</div>
```

When I click on one any of the elements, the `event.target` is that element.

I want to always get the div as the `event.target`. Is there any way to stop the children from firing events ?

Note : This question is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli). As what is asked in that question is exactly the other way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent a parent's onclick event from firing when a child anchor is clicked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli)

Comment: @noob : I want the parent to catch it and the children not to catch. It's exactly the reverse.

Comment: It falls into same category. `Event Bubbling`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass container div with `this` inside your handler, will return `f`:

```
<div id="f" onclick="f(this)">f
  <div id="1">1</div>
  <div id="2">2</div>
  <div id="3">3</div>
</div>

function f(el) {
   alert(el.id)
}
```

Demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/da26Lo60/)

Comment: Is it possible to have access to the event ? why when I take out `this` , nothing happens anymore ? no event is fired .

Comment: Yes, event is available inside that function, e.g. add `console.dir(event);` before or after alert. I updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/da26Lo60/)

Comment: Why you want to remove `this` from `onclick="f(this)"` ?

Comment: I just wanted to see if it is possible to have access to event. which is fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you always want the element that the event listener is attached to, then access the `currentTarget` property on the event object, `event.currentTarget`, instead of `event.target`.

The `currentTarget` property is the element that the event listener is currently attached to (which in your case would be the `div` with the `onclick` attribute).

```
<div onclick="clickHandler(event)"></div>
```

```
function clickHandler(event) {
  console.log('Event is attached to: ', event.currentTarget);
  console.log('The element clicked was: ', event.target);
}
```

---

In addition, if you pass the `this` keyword as a parameter, it would also refer to that element as well. You can use the `.call()` method in order to set the value of `this` in the function callback.

Update your `onclick` attribute to the following:

```
<div onclick="clickHandler.call(this, event)"></div>
```

And then your function's `this` keyword would refer to that `div` element and `event` would be passed as the first parameter:

```
function clickHandler(event) {
  console.log('Event is attached to: ', event.currentTarget);
  console.log('The element clicked was: ', event.target);
  console.log('"this" refers to: ', this);
}
```

Example demonstrating this:

```css
div { border: 1px solid; height: 200px; width: 200px; }
```

```html
<script>
function clickHandler(event) {
  console.log('Event is attached to: ', event.currentTarget);
  console.log('The element clicked was: ', event.target);
  console.log('"this" refers to: ', this);
}
</script>

<div onclick="clickHandler.call(this, event)">
  <span>'event.currentTarget' is the div</span>
  <span>'this' is also the div</span>
</div>
```

---

> Is there any way to stop the children from firing events?

You could check if `event.target` is `event.currentTarget`.

In the snippet below, the `if` statement will be true when clicking outside of the children elements and it will be false when clicking the children elements directly:

```
function clickHandler(event) {
  if (event.target === event.currentTarget) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Basic example:

```css
div { border: 1px solid; height: 200px; width: 200px; }
```

```html
<script>
function clickHandler(event) {
  console.log(event.target === event.currentTarget);
}
</script>

<div onclick="clickHandler(event)">
  <span>Click outside of a span</span>
  <span>Another span</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like that there's a problem here. If I click on element1. Then then it doesn't pass the if and it won't be caught at all. right ?

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh I updated my answer. I hope that clears it up for you. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

The children will fire the events. But if there's no function for those events, it will go to the parent.

You can stop event propagation to the the parent objects. But it's different in different browsers. I wrote a function to try to stop event propagation in all browsers. You call it from your javascript function that caught the event. Also, return false; in your function that caught the event.

```
function cancelEvent(e)
{
  e = e ? e : window.event;
  if(e.stopPropagation)
    e.stopPropagation();
  if(e.preventDefault)
    e.preventDefault();
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  e.cancel = true;
  e.returnValue = false;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: If I stop propagation, then the event won't be caught , right ? but I want the parent to "catch" it.