# Are nested anchors within a routerLink possible?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to put some anchors (`<a>` elements) within a larger clickable element (also `<a>`), which is a routerLink.

A simplified layout:

```
<div>
  <a [routerLink]="['/details', item.id]">
    <div>Lots of visual elements...</div>
    <div><a href="https://wikipedia.org">click here for more info...</a></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

[Simple Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/B63miQllMCn15Kp0VCIY?p=preview)

Looks like the outside [routerLink] intercepts all clicks within, so wikipedia link still navigates to details view, although it displays a wikipedia address on hover. The same happens even if the nested link is also a [routerLink].

Is there a way to suppress the outside [routerLink] when clicking on the nested link?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the parent anchor tag with a div tag, and it will work:

```
<div>
  <div [routerLink]="['/details', item.id]">
    <div>Lots of visual elements...</div>
    <div><a href="https://wikipedia.org">click here for more info...</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Updated Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4CT5Oe8ADc2yfsjUwycP?p=preview)

---

**Updated answer:**

Because you don't want to load the detail component you need to do something more here:

You want to prevent the click behaviour of the parent routerLink. So you need `event.stopPropagation` [see answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli).

So what you need to do is this:

Create a function `externalLink` in your App-Component:

```
externalLink(event, link: string){
    event.stopPropagation();
    window.location.href = link;
}
```

The anchor now looks like this:

```
<a (click)="externalLink($event, 'https://wikipedia.org')">
    Nested external link: check wikipedia
</a>
```

Check out the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/OO3fuWB0VRnGulXH0LI0?p=preview).

Comment: It at least ends up at wikipedia. But before it does it navigates to the outer link (displays details briefly). This can be seen in Plunker, and is even more apparent in my real-life application.
Additionally, the nested [routerLink] doesn't work.

Comment: please check out my updated answer, I hope it helps you ;)

Comment: it's still not ideal. So that this link looks like a proper link you need to leave `href="https://wikipedia.org"` there. This way it can be hovered and right-clicked in a usual manner. However, `ctrl+click` does too much - it does what the `(click)` does - changes the current page to wikipedia - and also opens wikipedia link in a new tab. So you'd need to add more logic in your method, but it all becomes too cumbersome. I was wondering if there's a simpler and more elegant solution.