# React event handling together with plain JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, kendo-ui

I have a situation when I have to render React controls in some code that I do not control. It's a kendo UI grid and I need to render custom React component in the grid cells.

Grid is created using jQuery under the hood. It also addes a `click` event listener for the parent html element (on the table row). In my React component I also have a `click` event listener. The problem is that the handler attached to the parent fires first.

The Snippet below (also available as a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/txytad68/)) demonstrates the issue. To keep this example as simple as possible I just use a `div` instead of the Kendo grid. The point is we have an event handler on the parent html element, then we render the React component into this parent element with its `click` handler, and the parent element takes precedence over React.

```js
class Btn extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.click = this.click.bind(this);
  }

  click() {
    alert('Btn');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <span onClick={this.click}>Click me</span>
    );
  }
};

$(function() {

  $('#container').on('click', function() {
    alert('JS');
  });

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Btn />,
    document.getElementById('btn')
  );

});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="btn">
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can put your example **here, on-site** as a runnable Stack Snippet; they support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). That might help you get answers.

Comment: (I went ahead and did it for you.)

Comment: Do you want to keep both event listener? The simple solution could be to programmatically remove the event listener that bothers you. By the way, this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1369080/5860648

Answer (score 1):

It's unfortunate, but as near as I can tell you can't tell React to bind its handlers deeper in the tree (it uses `document`, then uses delegation from there).

To get around it, you'd do a kind of [uncontrolled component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) (that's linked from [Integrating with Other Libraries](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html)) and use a [`ref`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to hook your handler up:

First we set up the ref:

```js
<span ref={span => this.span = span}>Click me</span>
```

Then we use [lifecycle methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle) to add and remove our handler:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.span.addEventListener("click", this.click);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.span.removeEventListener("click", this.click);
}
```

Live example:

```js
class Btn extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.click = this.click.bind(this);
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.span.addEventListener("click", this.click);
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.span.removeEventListener("click", this.click);
  }

  click() {
    alert('Btn');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <span ref={span => this.span = span}>Click me</span>
    );
  }
};

$(function() {

  $('#container').on('click', function() {
    alert('JS');
  });

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Btn />,
    document.getElementById('btn')
  );

});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="btn">
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

(If you need to support obsolete browsers without `addEventListener`, either use jQuery, or if you don't want the dependency [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23799448/157247) has a small cross-browser function for hooking events. You'd need to write your own unhook counterpart.)

You could even take it further and only hook up a single click handler, at the level of the element where you've mounted your component, and do your own event delegation (or use jQuery's) to dispatch as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's exactly what I need but I already did it with pure jQuery. Component was quite simple, so I just did all html creation and event handling manually.

Answer (score 0):

This should not longer be a problem with the native implementation of the Kendo Grid for React. As the events that grid is listening to are attached using React, and not jQuery, so they follow the bubbling in React. Thus you can cancel them from the child if you want. 
See the source of [this demo](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/editing/editing-custom/) that have some custom components in custom cells.