# How can I prevent an event from being activated in a child element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like the event not to be activated in the input.

[image]

My code html

```
<header>
    <nav class="titlebar" ondblclick="test()">
       <input class="box" type="text">
       <hr> 
    </nav>
</header>
```

my code js

```
function test() {
alert('holi')
```

}

Comment: Listen for the event in the child element and cancel it by `stopPropagation`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent a parent's onclick event from firing when a child anchor is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli)

Answer (score 4):

You can conditionally check for the input. 
If you would like to avoid more elements, you can check for a characteristic like class name.

```js
function test(e) {
  if(e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement && e.target.type == 'text') {
    console.log("INput clicked");
  } else {
    console.log("somewhere else");
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav class="titlebar" ondblclick="test(event)">
       <input class="box" type="text">
       <hr> 
    </nav>
</header>
```

Another way would be to attach a listener to the child element:

```js
function test() {
  console.log("clicked container");
}

function stop(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();  //Stops propagation to parent
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav class="titlebar" ondblclick="test(event)">
       <input class="box" type="text" ondblclick="stop(event)">
       <hr> 
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks, my problem was solved @Boy With Silver Wings !! :D

Comment: Happy to Help. You can accept the answer it helps @MarkColling