# Ignore parent onclick when child onclick is clicked, using Javascript only

Tags: javascript, html, css

An good example of what im trying to do is, think of instragram. When you are click on a photo, it opens a window with that photo plus the grey background. If you click anywhere in the grey background the picture is closed, however if you click on the picture the picture remains in the window.

This is what I am trying to achieve with this:

```
<div class="overlay_display_production_list_background" id="overlay_display_production_list_background_id" onclick="this.style.display = 'none'">
    <table class="table_production_availability" id="table_production_availability_id" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display = 'block'">
    </table>

</div>
```

However this doesnt work. how do I get this working, I only want Purely java-script.

Thanks

Comment: can u prepare a codepen / jsfiddle with more code to help you on these?

Comment: display:none on the div will make the table also no more visible ... the end ..

Comment: Yes I know Temani, and its meant to make the table no more visible unless you click only in the table

Comment: This might help <br> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Avoid intrinsic event attributes (like `onclick`). Bind your event handlers with JavaScript. Take advantage of the event object to prevent further propagation of the event up the DOM (so it never reaches the parent and thus doesn't trigger the event handler bound to it).

```js
document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("click", parent);
document.querySelector("div div").addEventListener("click", child);

function parent(event) {
  console.log("Parent clicked");
}

function child(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log("Child clicked");
}
```

```css
div {
  padding: 2em;
  background: red;
}

div div {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You perhaps can take an inner div which is absolute that has the background and certain height and width which is equal to main parent div and that has all the style, so on click of that div you may close parent div and on image you need not to do anything.

```
<div Parent><div Childdiv>
</div>
<img>
</div>
```

So childdiv should have display none functionality.
With JavaScript, you should be able to close parent div on a click of child div.