# stopPropagation & preventDefault are not working, parent click is still firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code, I have added `onclick` on parent div and want to perform other action on inner div, but clicking on inner div also triggering parent click.
how to stop that?

```js
$(document).on('click', '.child', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('child');
});

function parentfun(sender) {
  console.log('parent');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent" onclick="parentfun(this)">
  parent
  <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
```

**Above divs are generated on run time on some other event.**

Clicking on child, also trigger parent's click. preventDefault & stopPropagation are not working.

FYI: my question is different than [How do I prevent a parent's onclick event from firing when a child anchor is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent a parent's onclick event from firing when a child anchor is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli)

Comment: jQuery uses its own implementation of native events, have you checked if that is the reason?

Answer (score 5):

What you are actually doing here is binding the click-event to the document, not the child-element. So the event has already bubbled up all the way to the document, it's too late to try to stop the bubbling with stopPropagation.

See here when I change the click-handler to the child instead:

```js
$(".child").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('child');
});

function parentfun(sender) {
  console.log('parent');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent" onclick="parentfun(this)">
  parent
  <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
```

**Edit**

As the question changed a bit, here is what you can do (for example) if the elements are created dynamically:

```js
  $(document).on('click', '.parent, .child', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($(this).is(".child")) {
      console.log('child');
    } else {
      console.log('parent');
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  parent
  <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very well spotted!

Comment: Your code is working as expected but in my case, those parent and child divs generates on run time based on some other event, so i cannot attach the event directly on child div (i guess).

Comment: What if i use onclick="childfunc(this)" on child div also?

Comment: I will add an edit to the question as per the changes to the question.

Comment: @Esko: changing parent's event from onclick to $(document).on('click'  is not possible for me. But I can do anything with child.

Answer (score 1):

Using plain vanilla JS it works as expected:

```js
function logEventTarget(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log(e.target.id);
}

parentDiv.addEventListener('click', logEventTarget)
childDiv.addEventListener('click', logEventTarget)
```

```html
<div id="parentDiv">
  parent
  <div id="childDiv">child</div>
</div>
```

Using an inline event handler won't pass the event to the handler function:

```js
function logEventTarget(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log(e.target.id);
}

childDiv.addEventListener('click', logEventTarget)
```

```html
<div id="parentDiv" onclick="logEventTarget()">
  parent
  <div id="childDiv">child</div>
</div>
```

One of the many reasons you shouldn't use inline event handlers at all. Note that `e.stopPropagation()` still works for the `childDiv`.

Answer (score 0):

You can notice that when clicking the chlid element the parent triggers first (that is why parent prints first then child ) because of `event capturing` which precedes `event bubbling`. In-order to stop the `event capturing` phase from parent you can stop propagating that event and then only child event will trigger.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.child', function(e) {
  //e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('child');
});

$(document).on('click', '.parent', parentfun);
function parentfun(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('parent');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  parent
  <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also resolve this problem by editing little bit in Your html code

```
<div class="parent" id="parent-div">

<!-- Just adding parent div text inside span tag -->

<span>parent</span>

<div class="child">child</div>

</div>
```

now go to jquery code

```
 $('.parent span').on('click',function(){

  //only print child text u can do more

  alert($('.child').text());

  //Change color of child

  $('.child').css('color','red');

});
```

Comment: cannot change parent div