# Div to toggle it's display on/off but be able to click the input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make it so that whenever you click on either the button OR div itself, the display toggles. But whenever I click on the input inside of the div, the div disappears.

How can this be made so that you can still click on the input and the div not disappear? I've tried setting a z-index to the input but this fails.

Appreciate any help, thank you.

```js
function doThis() {
  var el = document.querySelector('div');
  
  if (el.style.display === 'flex') {
      el.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        el.style.display = 'flex';
      }
}
```

```css
div {
  background: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='doThis()'>click me</button>

<div onclick='doThis()'>
  text <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: You can't using `display:none` as it hides the element and all it's contents. You might be able to do somthing with `visibility` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the input click not to trigger the div click, you can use `event.stopPropagation()` function. It prevents event bubbling (passing the event to higher level DOM-elements).

```js
function doThis() {
  var el = document.querySelector('div');

  if (el.style.display === 'flex') {
      el.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        el.style.display = 'flex';
      }
}
```

```css
div {
  background: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='doThis()'>click me</button>

<div onclick='doThis()'>
  text <input onclick='event.stopPropagation()' type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: interesting. it works on this demo but not on my task. What does the (event) part mean? does it have to be called (event)?

Comment: `event` is a global that contains the last fired event on page (in case of onclick handler this will obviously be a `click` (also called `MouseEvent` in some browsers).

Answer (score 2):

For a pure JavaScript solution (that doesn't need jQuery), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29499060/1798629) from @Sabaz to *[How do I prevent a parent's onclick event from firing when a child anchor is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli)*:

> ```
> document.getElementById("clickable").addEventListener("click", function( e ){
>     e = window.event || e; 
>     if(this === e.target) {
>         // put your code here
>     }
> });
> ```
>
> Your code wont be executed if clicked on parent's childs

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
function doThis(evt) { // <-- new: add argument
  evt.preventPropagation() // <-- new, works in all new browsers
  var el = document.querySelector('div');

  if (el.style.display === 'flex') {
      el.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        el.style.display = 'flex';
      }
}
```

And add to your html:

```
onclick='doThis(event)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Why cant you implement event stopPropagation for all input objects, Try ..

```
// select elements with js selectors and bind it
document.querySelector('input').onclick = function(e){
   e.stopPropagation()
};
```

and here is answer by [Rex M](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1369080/3164682)

Answer (score 1):

Just check the target element which is clicked

```
function doThis() {
 if(event.target.nodeName != "INPUT"){
 var el = document.querySelector('div');
   if (el.style.display === 'flex') {
     el.style.display = 'none';
   } else {
     el.style.display = 'flex';
   }
  }
}
```