# How to prevent click of parent div when child is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `div` with an `<a href>` inside it. When the div is clicked I want to show a popup but when the anchor is clicked, I want to show a different modal.

```
 <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#firstmodal">
  <div>
   other stuff
  </div>
  <a href="" class="anch" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#other">
  <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

I tried to give `position:absolute; z-index:100` to the anchor tag, but it did not work. Clicking on it still opens BOTH the modals

```
.anch{
  position:absolute:
  z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: show you full working code here....

Comment: How do I prevent a parent's onclick event from firing when a child anchor is clicked?:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent a parent's onclick event from firing when a child anchor is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) in the link click event handler function to prevent further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases:

```js
document.querySelector('[data-toggle=modal]').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  alert('You have clicked div');
});

document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('You have clicked link');
});
```

```html
<div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#firstmodal">
  <div>
   other stuff
  </div>
  <a href="" class="anch" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#other">
  <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Test link
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The term you're looking for is the “propagation” of the event, up the element hierarchy.

You may want [Event.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault), or one of the other [methods to deal with event propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=stop%20propagation).