# trigger event only on parent click not child

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener

Consider the following code as an example:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">info goes here</div>
</div>

//javascript
function something{
//do something;}
//initial attempt
document.getElementById('parent').addEventListener('click',something);
//event capture
document.getElementById('parent').addEventListener('click',something,true);
```

When I click on the parent element I would like it to do something, and when I click the child I want it to do nothing.  The problem is that when I click in the child element it is triggering 'something'.
I thought that it may be event bubbling, such that if I clicked on the child element, the event would bubble up from there to the parent.  So then I was thinking about an event capture, but that also causes this problem.

Any advice or suggestions on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent a parent's onclick event from firing when a child anchor is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `event.stopPropagation` to stop event bubbling:

```js
function something() {
  console.log("something");
}
document.getElementById('parent').addEventListener('click', something);
document.getElementById('child').addEventListener('click', e => e.stopPropagation());
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  Parent info goes here!
  <div id="child">Child info goes here!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it solved my problem.  So if I understand correctly, even though I clicked on the child it was still the 'click' event that bubbled up and then triggered the parents listener?

Comment: Yes, that's correct - and that's what `stopPropagation` stops happening.

Comment: @PaulCarlson you should better not use `Event.stopPropagation()` and specially not assigning an event listener to every single element that you want to prevent the event from bubbling. It's incorrect.

Answer (score 8):

Instead, add the event only to the parent element, and check if **the element originating the event [`Event.target.closest(selector)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) - was indeed the desired element selector**.
*PS*:  Don't confuse `Event.target` with [Event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) which (in contrast) is always the Element who has the Event handler attached.

```js
const elParent = document.querySelector("#parent");

function doStuff(evt) {
  if (evt.target.closest("#child")) {
    console.log("Do child stuff only");
  } else {
    console.log("Do parent stuff only (not if child is clicked)");
  }
}

elParent.addEventListener("click", doStuff);

// Additional example on why you should avoid `Event.stopPropagation()`:
document.body.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("(App was notified) Closing some opened popup, etc");
});
// and BODY should always be notified about events! And this works as expected.
```

```css
#parent, #child {
  padding: 1rem;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <b>PARENT</b> ELEMENT
  <div id="child">CHILD ELEMENT</div>
</div>
```

**Don't use `Event.stopPropagation()`**

`Event.stopPropagation()` would be an idea, **but a bad one**. We should avoid an application layer to not register an event that occurred deeper in the DOM tree. We should let an event to freely bubble - and eventually notify other elements that such an event happened.
Imagine a `body` listening for click events in order to close a recently opened custom dropdowns, modal, etc. If you have elements wandering around your app that use `Event.stopPropagation()` - clicking on such an element the opened dropdown would not close, resulting in a **broken UI**. And this was just a simple example.
Of course one could catch an event on *app-level* even if a *component* uses `Event.stopPropagation()` by using the Event capture phase `{capture: true}`, but not many developers do so.

Here's a **discouraged**(!) way to use `Event.stopPropagation()` but still catch events on app-wise-level:

```js
const elParent = document.querySelector("#parent");
const elChild = document.querySelector("#child");

function doChildStuff(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation(); // DISCOURAGED. Avoid 
  console.log("Do child stuff only");
}

function doParentStuff(evt) {
  console.log("Do parent stuff");
}

elChild.addEventListener("click", doChildStuff);
elParent.addEventListener("click", doParentStuff);

// Additional example: proper planning for `Event.stopPropagation()`:
document.body.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("(App was notified) Closing some opened popup, etc");
}, {capture: true}); // PROPER WAY, since we use Event.stopPropagation()
```

```css
#parent, #child {
  padding: 1rem;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <b>PARENT</b> ELEMENT
  <div id="child">CHILD ELEMENT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice alternative to the standard answer, and illustrates why using `stopPropagation` might be a bad idea (ie: other elements like `body` might need to know about the click). It's also a good approach for a case where a parent might want to ignore clicks on several children, without having to add `stopPropagation` to each one individually.

Comment: Exactly. Thank you for the support @ericgio

Comment: is it safer to use `event.currentTarget` rather than `this` to prevent unexpected behaviour in arrow function, so `event.currentTarget` === `event.target`

Answer (score 0):

It is event bubbling. Just because you are handling the click event on the `child`, does not mean it stops bubbling to the parent.

There are two approaches to this. The first one is to stop the event from propagating like this:
`document.getElementById('child').addEventListener('click',(e) => { e.stopPropagation(); something() },true);`

The second is to check the event target and only run `something` when the deepest element that caused the click event is the child element:

`document.getElementById('child').addEventListener('click',(e) => { e.target.id == "child" ? something() : nothing() },true);`