# Calling a function on ONCLICK event

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, user-experience

I'm calling a function by ONCLICK event for the div conatiner but it also being called when I click on its inner elements so how can I call the function only for the div container not for its inner elements?

I have added just Onclick event on the container div and calling my close function

```
function closeMenu() {
    var target = document.getElementById("login-container");
    target.style.opacity = "0";
    target.style.zIndex = "-10";
}
var closeBtn = document.getElementById("close-overlay");
closeBtn.addEventListener("click", closeMenu);
```

I dont wanna call the function if i click on its inner HTML elements, just for the container div.

Comment: You can find the answer here => [How do I prevent a parent's onclick event from firing when a child anchor is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent a parent's onclick event from firing when a child anchor is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps.

```
function closeMenu(e) {
 if (e.target.id === "close-overlay"){
    var target = document.getElementById("login-container");
    target.style.opacity = "0";
    target.style.zIndex = "-10";
  }
}
var closeBtn = document.getElementById("close-overlay");
closeBtn.addEventListener("click", closeMenu);
```

Comment: Please don't answer duplicates

Comment: i miss it sorry

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to stop the propagation of the event. You just need to add `e.stopPropagation();`

[Here](https://codepen.io/NehhaSharma/pen/qBBRqEQ?editors=1111) is the code example of the same

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var closeBtn = document.getElementById("close-overlay");
closeBtn.addEventListener("click", closeMenu);

function closeMenu(e) {

 var child = document.getElementById("login-container"),
     parent = document.getElementById("close-overlay");

 if(e.target == parent){
    child.style.opacity = "0";
    child.style.zIndex = "-10";
  }

}
```

[working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/samsadtler/3d7941L2/34/)