# When clicking on the child don't consider the parent

Tags: html, css

I want some method to convince CSS that when I click on one of the children inside the parent element don't consider that I clicked also on the parent element.
I want you to try clicking on one of the children inside the parent.

```css
  .parent{
    background: blue;
    padding:20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
  }
  .parent:active{
    background: #ddd;
  }
  .child{
    background: red;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 4em;
  }
  .child:nth-child(odd){
    background: pink;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Click me</div>
   <div class="child">Click me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could do this with javaScript. I don't think you can do it just with css. Would a js solution be acceptable ?

Comment: I have no problem, and I think that your reply will be necessary for someone in future.

Comment: with css you can go only ' down ' the DOM . From parent to child. You cannot go from child to parent. So in your case, you want to access and change the parent when something happens to the child. That's not possible with just CSS

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the CSS `:active` behavior cannot be changed through CSS.

> The :active pseudo-class is commonly used on  and  elements. Other common targets of this pseudo-class include elements that contain an activated element, and form elements that are being activated through their associated .

A solution for this would to create your own behavior through JavaScript. When clicking the parent, check if the mouse is on the parent itself or a child inside of it. When it is the parent add a class to the parent element. And remove that class when releasing the mouse.

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');

parent.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  if (event.target === parent) {
    parent.classList.add('active');
  }
});

parent.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
  parent.classList.remove('active');
});
```

```css
.parent{
    background: blue;
    padding:20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
  }
  .parent.active {
    background: #ddd;
  }
  .child{
    background: red;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 4em;
  }
  .child:nth-child(odd){
    background: pink;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Click me</div>
   <div class="child">Click me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have no problem to use Javascript for a solution for this problem, anyway I am using Javascript currently, but is it possible to fix this problem through CSS? I am asking because if someone in the future read my question and he wanted to implement this functionality using only CSS

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 1):

Give the parent div

```
pointer-events: none;
```

No javascript needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript, you can simply prevent triggering the `:active` on the parent, using `preventDefault` for `mousedown` event on the children:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.child').forEach(child =>
  child.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  })
);
```

```css
.parent {
  background: blue;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.parent:active {
  background: #ddd;
}

.child {
  background: red;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 4em;
}

.child:nth-child(odd) {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Click me</div>
  <div class="child">Click me</div>
</div>
```