# div block is listening to both inner and outer events

Tags: javascript, html, css

On clicking black (outer div) outer is printed (no issue with that) but on clicking brown (inner div) both inner and outer is printed and thats the issue. I want only inner to be printed on clicking in brown area and outer on black area.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body style="height:100px; width:100px;">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: black;" onclick="console.log('outer')">
        <div style="width: 50%; height: 50%; background-color: brown;" onclick="console.log('inner');"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)

Comment: This is happening because inner div is still a part of outer div and will trigger the outer onclick event. You need to handle this using JS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The cancelBubble property of the Event interface is a historical alias to Event.stopPropagation(). Setting its value to true before returning from an event handler prevents propagation of the event.

```html
<body style="height:100px; width:100px;">
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: black;" onclick="console.log('outer')">
    <div style="width: 50%; height: 50%; background-color: brown;" onclick="console.log('inner');event.cancelBubble=true"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

you can use `event.cancelBubble=true` to achieve what you want

here you can read more about [cancelbubble](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/cancelBubble)

Comment: Upvoted, because this works, but the [global event property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) is deprecated, although still widely supported. A better answer might include that information, and demonstrate the correct way to set an event listener with [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make use of the `stopPropagation()` method. In this way you can prevent event "bubbling" on child/parent elements.

More info about it can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_stoppropagation.asp

Answer (score 0):

With the markup currently how it is, whenever you click the inner div you are also clicking the outer div, therefore both events will trigger.

The only way (to my knowledge) of overcoming this with plain html / css / js would be wrapping inner and outer in a container div with `display : grid` and then setting the appropriate grid areas:

```
.container {
   display : grid;
   grid-template : "a a a"
                   "a b a"
                   "a a a";
}
.outer {
   grid-area : a;
}

.inner {
   grid-area : b;
}
```

This is a bit of a strange solution though, and using jQuery could really help you here, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli?rq=1) for solving that way.