# Make a button inside of container clickable first rather then container

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

In a Chrome extension, I am gathering all images in a list. Then I add a button on top of every image, that is done for every webpage. On some websites, images are sitting inside of the container which is clickable, so when I am clicking the button it clicks the container too. Preventing bubbling does not help... because the container is on top??? Here is an example of what I have tried:

```
    $(img).wrap( '<div class="unblurButtonContainer"></div>')
    $('<button/>')
        .text('Btn')
        .addClass('unblurBtn')
        .css({'width': $(img).width(), 'height': $(img).height()})
        .appendTo($(img).parent())
        .click((event) => {
            event.preventDefault()
            event.stopPropagation()
            console.log("btn pressed")
            console.log(img)
        })
```

The clickable element is one of the parent nodes of the image. Is there any way to prevent it from being clicked?

Comment: That's how JavaScript tells you what you is doing is not right

Comment: @Ernesto. what would be the right way?

Comment: Is this right? `$('<button/>')` This doesn't look right to me. Wouldn't it just be `$('button')`

Comment: @RobMoll That creates a button and attaches it to the parent of the img, which is a div element I am using for wrap.

Comment: This SO answer might be helpful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1369080/13160984

Comment: Is hard to tell, specially when you didn't tell us what is this for