# How can I click an element positioned over another element without triggering both click events?

Tags: javascript

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/J7R1X/je5fsbkd/)

Is there a way to trigger the click event of a div inside another div without triggering the div on the containing elements click event?

```
<style>
#div1 {
  background-color: black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: white;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
</style>

<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  const div1 = document.getElementById('div1')
  const div2 = document.getElementById('div2')

  div1.onclick = () => {
    console.log("Div 1")
  }

  div2.onclick = () => {
    console.log("Div 2")
  }
</script>
```

How can I click the inner div without triggering click event of outer div?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: Duplicate: [How do I prevent a parent's onclick event from firing when a child anchor is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add `e.stopPropagation()` to the event.

```js
div2.onclick = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("Div 2")
}
```

[image]