# Clickable link within a clickable div, that voids parents's click event

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to have a clickable `div` with a nested `<a>`, that doesn't execute the click event on the `div` when the `<a>` tag is clicked?

Looking for a vanilla JS solution

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
div.addEventListener('click', e => {
  this.console.log('clicked the div');
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div> 
<p>This is a button</p>
<a href="/" target="_blank">Link to somewhere else</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prevent a parent's onclick event from firing when a child anchor is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli)

Comment: @Thibaut Yes this helps, when I add a clickevent on the nested <a> tag, that executes `e.stopPropagation()` on the `<a>`, it works the way I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check what element was the [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) of the event.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
div.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if(!e.target.matches('a'))
    console.log('clicked the div');
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div> 
<p>This is a button</p>
<a href="/" target="_blank">Link to somewhere else</a>
</div>
```