# Reactjs bootstrap button inside div with flex class not working

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, bootstrap-5, accordion

I am trying to put the button to edit content inside an accordion header and inside the accordion body. If I use a table without any class buttons work fine but with div with flex classes the buttons are not working. But with table the buttons are not aligned.

```
 <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
        {const.map((con,index) => (
            <Accordion.Item eventKey={con.ContentId} key={con.constId}>
            <Accordion.Header>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
                        <div>{index + 1}{')'} {con.Content}</div>
                        <div>
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-light mr-1" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                    data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onClick={() => editClick(con)}>Edit</button>
                        </div>

                </div>              
            </Accordion.Header>
            <Accordion.Body>
                {answers.map((ans,index) => (
                    <>
                     <div>{ans.constId == con.constId ? 
                     <div className="container">

                     <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
                       <div>{ans.Answer}</div>
                       <div>
                       <button type="button" className="btn btn-light mr-1" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                    data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onClick={() => editClick(con)}>Edit</button>                
                       </div>
                     </div>
       
                 </div>
                    : null}</div>
                    
                  </>    
                ))}          
        </Accordion.Body>
      </Accordion.Item>
        ))}
    </Accordion>
```

Comment: How is it not working? Perhaps you simply need `onClick={(e) => { e.stopPropagation(); ... }}`

Comment: It worked. Please add it to the answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prevent a parent's onclick event from firing when a child anchor is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli)

Comment: Yes. I added e.stopPropagation() and it worked.

Comment: Sorry, that's just how Stack Overflow announces duplicate votes. If the linked post answers your question, please accept the vote